# Concurrent queue which returns channels, locking doubts

Tags: go, concurrency, locking

There is queue of not important structs `Message`, which has the classic push and pop methods:

```
type Queue struct {
    messages list.List
}

//The implementation is not relevant for the sake of the question
func (q *Queue) Push(msg Message) { /*...*/ }
func (q *Queue) Pop() (Message, bool) { /*...*/ }

/*
 * NewTimedChannel runs a goroutine which pops a message from the queue every 
 * given time duration and sends it over the returned channel 
 */
func (q *Queue) NewTimedChannel(t time.Duration) (<-chan Message) {/*...*/}
```

The client of the `Push` function will be a web gui in which users will post their messages.
The client of the channel returned by `NewTimedChannel` will be a service which sends each message to a not relevant endpoint over the network.

I'm a newbie in concurrency and go and I have the following question:

I know that since `Queue.messages` is a shared state between the main goroutine which deals with pushing the message after the user submit a web form and the ones created for each `NewTimedChannel` invocation, I need to lock it.

**Do I need to lock and unlock using the `sync.Mutex` in all the Push, Pop and NewTimedChannel methods?**
**And is there a more idiomatic way to handle this specific problem in the go environment?**

Comment: 1. Yes. As can be seen if run under the race detector (which you should get used to do). 2. No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it requires synchronization or there will be a data race.

There is a saying in Go, "Don't communicate by sharing memory, share memory by communicating." As in this case, I think an idomatic way is to make channels send to a seprate goroutine which synchronize all the operations together using `select`. The code can easily be extended by adding more channels to support more kinds of operations (like the timed channel in your code which I don't fully understand what does it do), and by using `select` and other utils, it can easily handle more complex synchronizing by using locks. I write some sample code:

```
type SyncQueue struct {
    Q AbsQueue
    pushCh,popMsgCh chan Message
    popOkCh chan bool
    popCh chan struct{}
}

// An abstract of the Queue type. You can remove the abstract layer.
type AbsQueue interface {
    Push(Message)
    Pop() (Message,bool)
} 

func (sq SyncQueue) Push(m Message) {
    sq.pushCh <- m
}

func (sq SyncQueue) Pop() (Message,bool) {
    sq.popCh <- struct{}{} // send a signal for pop. struct{}{} cost no memory at all.

    return <-sq.popMsgCh,<-sq.popOkCh
}

// Every pop and push get synchronized here.
func (sq SyncQueue) Run() {
    for {
        select {
        case m:=<-pushCh:
            Q.Push(m)
        case <-popCh:
            m,ok := Q.Pop()
            sq.popMsgCh <- m
            sq.popOkCh <- ok
        }   
    }
}

func NewSyncQueue(Q AbsQueue) *SyncQueue {
    sq:=SyncQueue {
        Q:Q,
        pushCh: make(chan Message),popMsgCh: make(chan Message),
        pushOkCh: make(chan bool), popCh: make(chan struct{}),
    }
    go sq.Run()
    return &sq 
}
```

Note that for simpilicity, I did not use a quit channel or a `context.Context`, so the goroutine of `sq.Run()` has no way of exiting and would cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to lock and unlock using the sync.Mutex in all the Push, Pop and NewTimedChannel methods?

Yes.

> And is there a more idiomatic way to handle this specific problem in
>   the go environment?

For insight, have a look at the last answer for this question:

[How do I (succinctly) remove the first element from a slice in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531891/how-do-i-succinctly-remove-the-first-element-from-a-slice-in-go)